# Access the content of a webpage into current webpage through ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How can i insert the parsed html content into my webpage if i have only a link of the another webpage(get the html content from this webpage). I am using ajax call and i am getting the error i write the code below. And browser is not the issue
I want it as in Facebook but not in php

```
<script>
    jQuery.support.cors = true;

    $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url:"http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/3875-how-read-web-page-content-variable.html",
            dataType:"html",
            crossDomain:true,
                beforeSend: function(xhr) 
            {
                xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
            },
            success:function(data) {
                alert(data);
                $("body").html(data);
            },
            error:function(errorStatus,xhr) {
                alert("Error",errorStatus,xhr);
            }
        });

</script>
```

Comment: you can't do ajax to different servers

Comment: "am getting the error" — Why not tell us which error you are getting?

Comment: access denied is the problem here

Answer (score 0):

May be your browser don't support cors. 
http://caniuse.com/cors or another domain don't send back Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. 
Thanks for the comments made by Quentin.
Another option is to use jSONP.

```
<script>
var query = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=" + 
             encodeURIComponent("SELECT * FROM html WHERE url = 'http://www.hotscripts.com/forums/javascript/3875-how-read-web-page-content-variable.html'") + 
             "&format=json";
$.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: query,
        crossDomain:true,
            beforeSend: function(xhr) 
        {
            xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=UTF-8');
        },
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error:function(errorStatus,xhr) {
            alert("Error",errorStatus,xhr);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Third option is to make a request through a proxy script located on your domain.

In reply to:
 "i have used jQuery.support.cors=true; still there is a prob"
As I have said the server should return you the necessary headers.
If the other side does not allow it to become nothing can be done.
Check this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

To initiate a cross-origin request, a browser sends the request with an Origin HTTP header. The value of this header is the domain that served the page. For example, suppose a page from http://www.example-social-network.com attempts to access a user's data in online-personal-calendar.com. If the user's browser implements CORS, the following request header would be sent to online-personal-calendar.com:

```
 Origin: http://www.example-social-network.com
```

If online-personal-calendar.com allows the request, it sends an Access-Control-Allow-Origin header in its response. The value of the header indicates what origin sites are allowed. For example, a response to the previous request would contain the following:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://www.example-social-network.com

If the server does not allow the cross-origin request, the browser will deliver an error to example-social-network.com page instead of the online-personal-calendar.com response.

To allow access from all domains, a server can send the following response header:

```
 Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

This is generally not appropriate. The only case where this is appropriate is when a page or API response is considered completely public content and it is intended to be accessible to everyone, including any code on any site.

The value of "*" is special in that it does not allow requests to supply credentials, meaning HTTP authentication, client-side SSL certificates, nor does it allow cookies to be sent

Comment: "This is possible but only when you using JSONP" — err … What's `jQuery.support.cors = true;` then?

Comment: i have used jQuery.support.cors=true; still there is a prob